# Python: Inserting a Row into a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a more pythonic way to insert a row into a data frame? I feel like this has to be a functionality of pandas but can not find it. Especially, is there a way to 'reset' the indices?

Thank you.

```
data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
    'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
    'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

new =  pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(frame.columns)).reshape(1,len(frame.columns)),columns=frame.columns)
row = 3
def insert_row(frame,new,row):
    top = frame[0:row]
    bottom = frame[row:]
    return pd.concat((top,new,bottom))
```

However, running the above returns:

```
   pop   state  year
0  1.5    Ohio  2000
1  1.7    Ohio  2001
2  3.6    Ohio  2002
0  0.0       0     0
3  2.4  Nevada  2001
4  2.9  Nevada  2002
```

Comment: DataFrames have a `reset_index` method. So there's that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `loc` attribute to assign data. Syntax is `df.loc[row_index, col_index]`. An example:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(index=list('abcd'), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.loc['a', 'A'] = 1 # re-assigns an existing item
df.loc['b'] = [1, 2, 3, 4] # set the whole row
df.loc['e', 'E'] = 5 # creates a new row and column
df = df.reindex(list('abecd'))
print(df)

     A    B    C    D   E
a    1  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
b    1    2    3    4 NaN
e  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   5
c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
d  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
```

Comment: So, you're saying to just create a brand new row, and then re-index the rows to where you want the new row inserted.

I like it. Still hoping there's a built-in way to insert a row in a desired location.

Comment: I understand you as to what .loc does. I don't think I'm being clear on what i mean by 'insert' row. I don't mean append a row. I mean insert a row at a certain location. So, if i wanted to insert row 'e' between rows 'b' and 'c', I would first df.loc['e','E'] then df.reindex('a b e c d'.split())

Answer (score 0):

If your current function works well enough for you, I suggest just adding `reset_index` to the returned result. See something like below:

```
    ...:     return pd.concat((top,new,bottom)).reset_index(drop=True)

In [17]: new_frame = insert_row(frame, new, row)

In [18]: new_frame
Out[18]: 
   pop   state  year
0  1.5    Ohio  2000
1  1.7    Ohio  2001
2  3.6    Ohio  2002
3  0.0       0     0
4  2.4  Nevada  2001
5  2.9  Nevada  2002
```

The parameter `drop=True` forces it to drop the old index. Leaving it at `False` keeps the old index as a new first column.

Comment: Thank you for the reset_index option. That certainly improves my code.

Still hoping there's a built-in way to accomplish this.